# How to display my selected index in my php

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where index = '" . $index . "'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    results
        echo  $row['index'] . " | " . $row['name'] . " | " . $row['contact'] . " | " . $row['email'] ;

        }
```

Why I cannot display the selected $index? My result is empty.

**In my database the index is int and AUTO_INCREMENT, is it because the index is int, it cannot be found?

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* functions they have been deprecated in 5.5 and will be completely removed in 7. Use prepared statement in mysqli or PDO  libraries instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you since it is auto-incremented it you are likely to get only one row as result so when you call `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` for the first time youe values are being set in it and then when you call it again in your while loop it is getting blank.

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where `index` = '" . $index . "'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['index'] . " | " . $row['name'] . " | " . $row['contact'] . " | " . $row['email'] ;
```

Comment: If you insist on placing the $index in the sql this way you should at least use intval($index) to make sure no injectable text makes it's way in there.

Answer (score 3):

It might possible that your field `index` is conflict with MySQL reserved keyword `index` so put backtick(`) along that word like below and see the result

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where `index` = '" . $index . "'");
```

NOTE: Never use field name same as reserved keyword, it might conflict somewhere.

Comment: Index is a reserved keyword. Here's a link to a full list https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html.